# What apps are these notifications for?

Tags: notification-bar, notification-icons

[image]

Does anyone know what apps the notifications at the top left of the screen are for? I was sent a screenshot and I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

In newer Android versions you can **long-tap notifications** to reveal the app the notification came from.

Comment: The Flower is FING - The Message icon looks like Messenger or the default New SMS icon with theme's ... And the last one i suppose is a network analyser by Fing, just showing the active status.

Comment: FIRE LORD ... You have mistaken this question for someone that has access to the device... This person only got sent the picture... The duplicates aren't helpful at all. so this question is not a duplicate.